# Search a substring in an array of Strings in unityscript

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to search a substring in an array of Strings. I'm using the following code (in Unity3):

```
var obstacles = ["Border", "Boundary", "BoundaryFlame"];
var frontAvailable = true;
var leftAvailable = true;
var rightAvailable = true;
var hitFront: RaycastHit;
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.position + transform.forward, hitFront, 1.5)) {
    Debug.Log("I hit this in front: ");
    Debug.Log(hitFront.collider.gameObject.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++)
    {
       if (obstacles[i].IndexOf(hitFront.collider.gameObject.name) > -1)
       {
          Debug.Log("Hit in front!");
          frontAvailable = false;
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the Debug.Log shows `Boundary(Clone)`. I've included `Boundary` in the array `obstacles`. Shouldn't below code set `frontAvailable` to false? Or did I make a mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Kolink's answer, your `if` is looking for `Boundary(clone)` at the beginning of `Boundary`, rather than the other way around. I think you're looking for:

```
if (hitFront.collider.gameObject.name.IndexOf(obstacles[i]) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `indexOf`, not `IndexOf`. Assuming you're talking about the native string function.

In addition, `indexOf` returns `-1` if there is no match, `0` if the match is at the start, `1, 2, 3`... for further positions. So you need `> -1` instead of `> 0`

Comment: You are correct, it should be -1. I had that at first but changed it later for testing. It still doesn't work :( As for IndexOf, apperantly in Unity, I have to use the capital `I`. Else it doesn't recognize the method.

Comment: Fair enough, I haven't used Unity so I didn't know ;)

Comment: It is still JavaScript so I don't know where it's coming from. I was stuck on that exact same issue for almost an hour yesterday.............